# MySQL Grab From Table if Exists, otherwise use Different Table

Tags: mysql, sql, union

I need to select all IsActive columns where the value = 1 in a table, but if another table has a match on the ItemName columns, I need to grab that row from the other table instead.

Example: `table1`

```
--------------------------------------------
  ItemName  |  Cost  |  Price  |  IsActive
--------------------------------------------
  Item1     |  4.50  |   5.00  | 1
--------------------------------------------
  Item2     |  3.00  |  3.50   | 0
--------------------------------------------
  Item3     |  1.75  |  2.40   | 1
--------------------------------------------
  Item4     |  2.55  |  3.05   | 1
```

Example: `table2`

```
--------------------------------------------
  ItemName  |  Cost  |  Price  |  IsActive
--------------------------------------------
  Item1     |  5.50  |   6.70  | 1
--------------------------------------------
  Item8     |  3.00  |  3.50   | 0
--------------------------------------------
  Item8     |  3.50  |  4.50   | 1
--------------------------------------------
  Item3     |  2.75  |  3.40   | 1
--------------------------------------------
  Item5     |  2.60  |  3.90   | 1
```

Result Needs to be this:

```
--------------------------------------------
  ItemName  |  Cost  |  Price  |  IsActive
--------------------------------------------
  Item1     |  5.50  |   6.70  | 1
--------------------------------------------
  Item3     |  2.75  |  3.40   | 1
--------------------------------------------
  Item4     |  2.55  |  3.05   | 1
--------------------------------------------
  Item5     |  2.60  |  3.90   | 1
--------------------------------------------
  Item8     |  3.50  |  4.50   | 1
```

Basically, if the ItemName exists in table2, get it where IsActive = 1, otherwise get it from table1 where IsActive = 1.

How can I do this within a Single MySQL Statement?  Can someone provide an example?  Also, note, it is possible that `table2` will be completely empty also.  I need the result Ordered by `ItemName ASC` and all IsActive values need to be `1` ofcourse, since that will need to be set in the `WHERE clause`  I have pagination set on the query, and am using LIMIT (0, 20) on it also, so I need to keep pagination, so it needs to work within 1 Query.

This seems very basic to me, but yet I'm struggling on how to do this simple MySQL statement oddly.  If someone can provide a MySQL example of this, that would be preferred over SQL, since the 2 differ and am needing to use MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NOT EXISTS and UNION ALL like this:

```
select *
from table1 t1
where isActive = 1
    and not exists (
        select 1
        from table2 t2
        where t1.ItemName = t2.ItemName
            and t2.isActive = 1
        )

union all

select *
from table2 t1
where isActive = 1;
```

#### [Live demo](http://rextester.com/PURJ2275)

Comment: What does `select 1` do?

Comment: It will select value 1 for each row if there is a row present with the matching condition then, NOT EXISTS will check if there is any row present. It doesn't care about what the row contains.

Comment: @Solomon Added a demo for you

Comment: Thank many GurV, just what I needed here!  I knew this should be possible!